# Value of a unset column in :new pseudorecord before update oracle trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-update, database-trigger

I'm trying to know what is the value of a column in the `:new` pseudorecord in a `before update` oracle trigger when i dont explicit update this column but others?

Example:

```
create table example (cod number(10),name varchar(50),description varchar(50));
update example set description = 'value example' where cod = 1;
```

If a have a `before update` trigger on `example` table, what is the value of `:new.name`?. Remember I'm just updating `description` column.

Thanks

Comment: If this answers helped you in doubt, mark answer correct or vote up.

Answer (score 1):

> If a have a `before update` trigger on `example` table, what is the value of `:new.name`? Remember I'm just updating `description` column.

It will contain the value that is currently in the `name` column on the row that is being updated.

This is [quite easy to test](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2f03dc8ca50a6c8b7c7c5960d86a5b23):

```
create table example (cod number(10),name varchar(50),description varchar(50)); 

create trigger trg_example
before update on example
for each row
begin
    dbms_output. put_line('new name:' || :new.name);
end;
/

insert into example(cod, name, description) values(1, 'foo', 'bar');
-- 1 rows affected

update example set description = 'zoo' where cod = 1;
-- 1 rows affected
```

```
dbms_output:
new name:foo
```

Comment: Thanks, i already have tested it, but a want to be sure  that is the default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If a have a before update trigger on example table, what is the value of :new.name?
:new.name will contain the existing value of name only. see below example I have tried.

```
insert into example values(123,'name','dummy desc');
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER example_before_update 
BEFORE UPDATE of description 
   ON example 
   FOR EACH ROW 

  DECLARE 
   description varchar2(10); 
   name varchar2(50); 

 BEGIN 
 -- Update updated_description 
  description:=:new.description; 
  name:=:new.name; 
  dbms_output.put_line( 'description  ' || description); 
  dbms_output.put_line( 'name  ' || name); 

 END; 

  update example set description = 'newexm' where cod = 123;
```

And output will be as below

```
   1 row(s) updated.
   description newexm
   name name
```

Please refer below link for complete sample.
https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/jw4epiekg9l76g2zad19x04pc